# How is memory laid out and in which direction does the address get bigger? Using unions

Tags: c++, unions, memory-address

I was working on making a random number gen.  I am using a union to access bytes.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typdef unsigned char uchar;
union
{
uint intBits;
uchar charBits[4];
};
```

// Yes I know ints are not guaranteed to be 4 but ignore that.

So if the number 1 was stored in this union it would look like

```
00000000 0000000 00000000 00000001
```

right?

Would a int of -1 look like

```
00000000 0000000 00000000 00000001
```

or

```
10000000 0000000 00000000 00000001
```

so really the address of the uint is the bit that is 1 right?  And the address of charBits[0] is the bit that is 1 right?  The confusing thing is this.  charBits[1], would have to move to the left to be here

```
                        ! 
00000000 0000000 00000000 00000001
```

so do memory addresses get bigger right to left or left to right?

EDIT:
I am on a 64bit windows 7 system intel i7 CPU.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness Note that it'll depend on what convention you're using to print it.

Comment: Without knowning your platform your question is pretty much meaningless. Furthermore a lot of plattforms use two's complement for representing numbers, so `-1` is more likely to be `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`.

Comment: `-1` has to be `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`. Otherwise, if you add `1` to it, you won't get `0`!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: not necessarily, there are quite a few different representations. Two's complement is just the most popular since it makes addition/substraction very easy. Another option is for example a dedicated sign bit, representing`-1` as `10...01`. Of course this makes addition/substraction more complex (it does however make it easier to change the sign of a number and it may make multiplication easier, but I'd have to look it up to be sure). And yes other representations have actually been used in computers (though mostly not particulary recent ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the machine architecture.  If your CPU is big endian then it will work as you seem to expect:

int(4) => b3 b2 b1 b0

But if your CPU is little endian then the bytes are in the opposite direction:

int(4) => b0 b1 b2 b3

Note that bit orders within bytes are always from left (most significant) to right (least signficant).

Comment: so on my windows system int of 1 would be 1000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 or 00000001 0000000 0000000 0000000?

Comment: @EddieV223 Not quite, you've reversed bit order, but you're only supposed to reverse byte order. So it would be 00000001 00000000 00.... 0000

Comment: @EddieV223 No, it would be 00000001, 0, 0, 0

Comment: would the sign bit be for -1  0000001 0000000 0000000 X000000 where X is?

Comment: The sign bit is the most significant bit. -1 will be all bits set. (Because if you add 1 to it, you need to get 0. The only number that will do that is all bits set.)

Comment: oh so it would be 1111111 1111111 11111111 (1)1111111 the one in () being the most significant?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to do this at all. You can easily compose a 32-bit integer from 8-bit values like this:

```
int myInt = byte1 | (byte2<<8) | (byte3<<16) | (byte4<<24);
```

And you can easily decompose a 32-bit integer into 8-bit values like this:

```
byte1 = myInt & 0xff;
byte2 = (myInt >> 8) & 0xff;
byte3 = (myInt >> 16) & 0xff;
byte4 = (myInt >> 24);
```

So there's no reason to write non-portable, hard to understand code that relies on internal representation details of the CPU or platform. Just write code that clearly does what you actually want.